# Timeout when using NSUrlSession with call started in foreground but app moved to background

Tags: ios, timeout, nsurlsession

If a basic call to post some data to a server using NSURLSession (in this case using Alamofire) a call is started with the app in foreground, while the call is in progress the app is move to the background and is suspended. When the app comes back to the foreground, what happens to the call that was in progress? Does it timeout (App is using default 60 seconds ephemeralSessionConfiguration) or will it receive some other error? If the timeout has not yet been reached is the call still waiting or has the OS terminated it? I have the default background mode and have no requested no background time. Trying to debug an issue that happened in the field.

Answer (score -1):

Your network requests are suspended when your app is suspended.  So basically the answer is that it depends on whether the server gives up on you while your app is in the background, and on whether the socket in the kernel gives up on your app while it is suspended.

As a rule, if you need to move data while your app is in the background, you should be using a background session and a download or upload task.  That way, the actual data transfer happens in a separate process (that doesn't get suspended) and your app will get the data.

With that said, using a background session is fundamentally in conflict with using an ephemeral configuration, because it involves storing data on disk.  So if you really need an ephemeral configuration for some reason, your app's requests are likely to just fail a few seconds after the user hits the home button, and there's not much you can do about it as long as you're making requests ephemerally.